# what will be behavior of following code snippet?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, floating-point

What will be the behavior and output of the following code if i accidentally code so in C/C++,

```
float a = 12.5;
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", *(int *)&a);
```

Comment: Two words: Undefined Behaviour

Comment: The point of curiosity is to try it *intentionally* and see what happens :)

Comment: @Nikolai: but try it on more than one platform (preferably with different endianness or different sizeof(int))

Comment: Demons may fly out of your nose. http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/07/30/language-lawyers-and-nasal-demons.aspx

Comment: @Nikolai But whatever happens if he tries it is not very informative, such being the way of UB. Still, I take your point - sometimes I think I'm the only person on SO that actually owns a compiler.

Comment: BTW why -1? Pls let me know my mistake so that i dont repeat it.

Comment: @Prabhu, I suspect it was someone's way of saying they thought the question was nonsense. It didn't come from me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rubish and more rubish.

You would get something meaningful if you did the following though

```
 printf("%d\n", (int)a);
```

Comment: +1 for unintentional humour. :-)

Comment: @Paul R: How did you know it was unintentional? Not saying it wasn't mind you.

Comment: @torak: apologies if it was intentional - I thought it was probably just a typo that happened to be quite funny and apposite. :-)

Comment: @Paul R: No, it wasn't intentional. Actually, I appreciate you letting me in on my own joke. :)

Comment: @torak: cool - I may steal your joke at some later date. ;-)

Comment: Isn't it rubbish and not rubish? Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 0):

its undefined, because ANSI defines not a relation between sizeof(int) and sizeof(float).